# Must Understand check failed for header soapenv error in communicating with WAS

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, websphere-esb

I am calling a java webservice sitting on Websphere Application Server(WAS) from Websphere Enterprise Service Bus(WESB).
Provider has enabled security using JAAS.
So,I created WS-Security username token client policy set for my module.
The trace of my outbound call from WESB looks like

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Security xmlns:s="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
  <s:UsernameToken>
    <s:Username>**username**</s:Username>
    <s:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">**password**</s:Password>
  </s:UsernameToken>
</s:Security>
```

But the provider is expecting the Security payload to be sent as below with some namespace in Username tag

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security wsse:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">**username**</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">**password**</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I am getting the below error while invoking the java service

AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive Must Understand check failed for header soapenv : {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header soapenv : {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.handler.HandlerUtils.checkUnprocessed(HandlerUtils.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.handler.HandlerUtils.checkMustUnderstand(HandlerUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.inboundHeaderAndHandlerProcessing(EndpointController.java:363)

Is it the correct way to handle JAAS by creating WS Security client policy set or do I have to handle in different way.

Answer (score 2):

That wsu namespace that is on that UsernameToken in the 2nd example is there for wsu:Id.  The wsu:Id is only needed if something will reference the element.  You have nothing referencing the element, so it is not required.

If you were getting an error because the security handler didn't like the fact that the wsu:Id was missing, you would get a SoapSecurityException, not a MustUnderstand check.

A MustUnderstand check means that you have sent a header for which no handler in the runtime has marked as processed.  Either there is no handler registered to handle it or no registered handler marked the header.  For security headers, this usually means that there are no WS-Security constraints applied.

You can verify that there are no WS-Security constraints applied by sending a message with no Security header.

If you send a message that includes a Security header like your 2nd example?

Do you have security constraints on you client for responses?  You will get this same error if you have no constraints for responses but the server sent a Security header in the response.

This is what I would do:

1) Enable a WS-Security trace on the WAS server

com.ibm.ws.webservices.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.xml.soapsec.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.platform.audit.*=off:com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.AgnosticService=all:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.utils.SecurityContextMigrator=all

2) Restart the server

3) Send the message from the client

4) Search the trace for 'bound http'.

4a) You should see the Inbound HTTP SOAP Request

4b) search again

4c) You should see Outbound HTTP SOAP Response

4ci) Does the response have the expected response or a fault?

4cii) If the response is a fault, then you have a server issue

4cii) If the expected response, does the response contain a Security header?

4ciii) If yes, then the MustUnderstand check came from the client and you most likely need to apply security response constraints to your client.

5) If, in step 4, you determined that you have a server issue, search backwards in the trace for something that looks like this (on the current thread):

WSSecurityCon 3   isServerSide == true

WSSecurityCon 3   No PolicyType Binding

5a) If you see this, then you do not have security constraints applied to your provider application.  Here are some instructions for applying a UsernameToken policy in WebSphere (assuming that your app is JAX-WS):

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_stand_alone_security_token.html

**And for those that delete my posts because they have links:**

**Configuring a policy set and bindings for a stand-alone security token (UsernameToken or LTPA Token)**

You can secure web services by configuring the message-level WS-Security policy set and bindings for a stand-alone security token that is either a Lightweight Third Party Authentication (LTPA) token or a Username token.
Before you begin

This task assumes that the service provider and client that you are configuring are in the JaxWSServicesSamples application. See the documentation on accessing samples to learn how to obtain and install this application. Specify the following trace specification on your server to enable you to debug any future configuration problems that might occur.

*=info:com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.wssecurity.*=all: 
com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.*=all: com.ibm.xml.soapsec.*=all: com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.*=all: 
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.platform.audit.*=off:

If LTPA tokens are used, you must enable the application security on the application servers that are used for both the client and the service.
About this task

This topic describes how to configure a WS-Security policy set and provider bindings for a Username token or an LTPA token. For simplicity, this procedure demonstrates how to remove the timestamp, digital signature, and encryption attributes from the policy; however, you might want to include these attributes in your final configuration. To learn more, see the documentation on configuring a policy set and bindings for Asymmetric XML digital signature or XML encryption with client and provider application specific bindings.

In this task, default provider general bindings are used for the provider application to consume the tokens. If a caller configuration is required, an application-specific binding will be added for the provider.

Procedure

```
Create the custom policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Services > Policy sets > Application Policy sets.
    Click New.
    Specify Name = OneTokenPolicy.
    Click Apply.
    Under Policies, click Add > WS-Security.
Edit the custom policy set
    Remove digital signature, encryption, and timestamp.
        In the administrative console, clickWS-Security > Main Policy.
        Deselect Message level protection.
        Click Apply.
    Add the UsernameToken or LTPA token.
        Under Policy details, click Request token policies.
        Select Add Token Type.
        If you want to use a UsernameToken, select UserName. If you want to use an LTPA token, select LTPA.

        Token name=myToken.
        Click OK.
Configure the client to use the OneTokenPolicy policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Applications > Application types > WebSphere enterprise applications > JaxWSServicesSamples > Service client policy sets and bindings.
    Select the web services client resource.
    Click Attach Policy Set.
    Select OneTokenPolicy .
Create a custom binding for the client.
    Select the web services resource again.
    Click Assign Binding.
    Click New Application Specific Binding to create an application-specific binding
    Specify the bindings configuration name. name: oneTokenClientBinding
    Click Add > WS-Security
    If the Main Message Security Policy Bindings' panel does not display, select WS-Security.
Edit the custom binding for the client.
    Edit the identity token generator to send the identity username.
        Click request:myToken.
        Click Apply.
        Click Callback handler. User name=(yourUserid) Password=(yourPassword)
    Avoid trouble Avoid trouble: This is a userid/password that is valid on the user registry on the provider's system. If you are using LTPA tokens, the userid/password must be valid on both the consumer and provider registries.
    (Optional) If configuring a UsernameToken, add the following WS-Security custom properties:

    *com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.addNonce=true
    *com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.addTimestamp=true

    These custom properties are added because they are specified on the UsernameToken consumer default general bindings. If we do not specify those properties here, you will either need to remove those properties from the default provider general bindings or create application-specific bindings for the provider that does not include those properties.
    Click OK.
    Click Save
Configure the provider to use the OneTokenPolicy policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Applications > Application types > WebSphere enterprise applications > JaxWSServicesSamples > Service provider policy sets and bindings
    Select the web services provider resource (OneTokenPolicy)
    Click Attach Policy Set.
    Select OneTokenPolicy
    Note: Since no bindings are attached to the provider application, it will use the default provider general bindings for the token consumers.
(Optional) If you want to create a Caller configuration for the provider, create custom bindings for the provider.
    Select the web services provider resource again.
    Click Assign Binding
    Click New Application Specific Binding to create an application-specific binding
    Specify Bindings configuration name:oneTokenProvBinding
    Click Add > WS-Security
    If the Main Message Security Policy Bindings' Panel does not display, select WS-Security
(Optional) If a Caller configuration will be created, edit the custom bindings for the provider.
    Click Caller > New. Name: myCaller.
        If using a UsernameToken, enter the following:
            Caller identity local name: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken
        If using an LTPA token, enter the following:
            Caller identity local name: LTPAv2
            Caller identity local URI: http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype
    Click OK.
Click Save to save your configuration changes.
Restart the client provider.
    Stop the client and the provider
    Restart the client and the provider
Test the Service.
    Point your web browser at the JaxWSServicesSamples: http://localhost:9080/wssamplesei/demo
    Avoid trouble Avoid trouble: Make sure you provide the correct hostname and port if your profile is not on the same machine or the port is not 9080.
    Select Message Type Synchronous Echo
    Make sure Use SOAP 1.2 is not selected
    Enter a message and click Send Message. The sample application should reply with JAXWS==>Message.
```

Results

The JaxWSServicesSamples web services application is configured to generate and consume a UsernameToken or LTPA token in the request message.

Comment: thank you very much Barabara!
Actually,the  issue is with security compatibility
I have enabled WS-Security,but the provider is using user name token

Comment: Krishna, did you resolve your issue, or do you still need some assistance?  If you still need assistance, when you say 'the provider is using user name token', do you mean some user name token that is not WS-Security?  HTTP basic authentication maybe?

Comment: Yes, JAAS authentication alias,issue is resolved, provider changed their security to WS-Security